How does the presence of a Landau pole suggest a theory is trivial?
A theory is said to have a Landau pole if the coupling constant diverges at a finite energy scale. On Wikipedia it is said that the presence of a Landau pole could indicate the theory is trivial (i.e. the theory is a free theory in the UV limit). This seems counterintuitive since the Landau poles suggests the exact opposite, that the theory is as strongly coupled as possible.
How does the presence of a Landau pole suggest a theory is trivial? How are any of these statements to be taken seriously if perturbation theory is no longer valid once the theory is strongly coupled?

You may be misquoting WP. Look at its eqn (2), as well as this article. The theory is IR free. Perturbation theory is an indicative harbinger. There are lattice methods to flesh out the trends indicated.

@CosmasZachos I think my troubles come from articles not specifying if they mean IR or UV triviality. As an example, the $\beta$-function of $\phi^4$ and QED in 4D suggests the couplings go to zero in the UV and diverge to infinity in the IR. Does this mean the Landau pole is in the IR? As a general rule can we say that if a theory has a Landau pole at low (high) energy then it is trivial at high (low) energy? I don't understand the connection between a theory having a Landau pole and it being trivial.

As a general rule,  we say that if a theory has a Landau pole at  high  energy then it is trivial at  low  energy.  The -functions of 4 and QED in 4D suggest the couplings go to zero in the  IR.

@CosmasZachos Why do we expect the low/high energies to have opposite behaviors? For example, what rules out them both having a Landau pole or being trivial, or there being a Landau pole or trivial point at an "intermediate" energy?

If you discount the inflammatory language, you might consider QCD which has a presumed coupling singularity at a finite energy of about 1/fm, and is asymptotically free: at much Higher energies, the coupling weakens to insignificance; while at energies much  Lower than 1 GeV the coupling is undefined--there are only effective couplings of hadron effective interactions, not the original coupling of the QCD QFT.

First have look at my previous answer
What is the Wilsonian definition of renormalizability?
for general explanations about UV renormalization and what one is trying to achieve. The new question relates to a very simple phenomenon in the the theory of ODEs and PDEs, in regards to global-in-time well-posedness. Consider a differential equation
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=\epsilon x^2
$$
where $\epsilon=\pm 1$.
In the focusing case $\epsilon=1$, the solution goes to infinity in finite time. In the defocusing case $\epsilon=-1$ one has the opposite phenomenon of "coming down from infinity". The solution becomes infinite if we run the equation backward in time. A sign of that is for $t_1<t_2$, one has a uniform bound on $x(t_2)$ regardless of the size of the initial condition $x(t_1)$ set at time $t_1$.
Here $t=-\log\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is the UV cutoff. The problem of UV renormalization is not about solving the ODE (given by the beta function) forward in time, but rather deciding on the value we want say for $x(0)$, an effective coupling at say unit scale, and then figuring out the initial condition $x(t)$ at $t=-\infty$ which allows us to realize the wanted value a time zero. For $\phi_4^4$ we are in the coming down from infinity situation, where for any $x(0)>0$ we find that there is no suitable initial condition at $t=-\infty$ because the solution diverges before, at a finite negative time. The only way to reach $t=-\infty$ is to take $x(0)=0$, i.e., when the theory obtained at the end of the day (after removing cutoffs) has zero effective coupling, i.e., is trivial. Note that all this is due to the sign of $\epsilon$, i.e., the bubble graph $>O<$. It has the opposite sign for gauge theories and Fermionic models like Gross-Neveu, hence asymptotic freedom and escaping this mechanism for triviality. Note that $x(0)<0$ would also work if one can define $\phi_4^4$ for negative coupling. This was done nonperturbatively, but only for planar graphs, by 't Hooft and Rivasseau.

Thank you. This is a very interesting view of renormalization and makes this issue of why some theories must be trivial a lot easier to understand. Does the ODE given by the beta function always have such a form, where a Landau pole at large (small) energy implies a trivial theory at small (large) energy?

This simple form is typical of the one-loop approximation which is often used in the physics literature. The true beta should include higher order corrections.
